# How to make graphics created with CreateGraphics() always visible on control without flickering

Tags: .net, winforms

I have custom control. I have OnPaint() event defined there. Let's say it's a text editing control. I want to display custom caret overlay.
I created a Graphics object with CreateGraphics().
If on each blink timer tick I call the code which draws caret - it's visible.
After some painting in OnPaint() my caret disappears. It can be redrawn, but when I tried to put DrawCaret() invocation at the end of main OnPaint() handler nothing happens.
The caret is not drawn, or it's drawn and cleared.

Forcing DrawCaret() in various places in code causes ugly flickering at best, does nothing at worst.
When I have DrawCaret() in blinkTimer_Tick() event handler - it's drawn, but it flickers irregularly.

And no, I don't want to use Win32 Caret - its color cannot be set. I need to draw my own caret and it has to blink.

If it has to blink, I assume I can't use control's OnPaint() event handler.

Comment: The Graphics object you get from CreateGraphics() splatters pixels to the screen directly.  They never last very long, a paint erases them again.  So losing the fake caret is pretty normal.  What else your code might be ailing is hard to guess at.  There ought to be plenty, creating a substitute for TextBox isn't that simple.  Just finding the proper place to draw the caret and restoring the anti-aliasing pixels you overdrew, all without flicker, is already a major headache.

Comment: Well, you're right. I dropped the idea to use separate Graphics object. I moved caret drawing to main OnPaint event and it works as charm. I'm not building the control from scratch, I'm fixing FTCB ;) Done, tested, pull request added :)

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It seems like it was a really bad approach. I've moved caret drawing to main OnPaint() and it works as charm.

I'm a little worried about Invalidate() I call every caret "blink", what if I created caret as a child control? Lighter or heavier? I guess I won't test it, the current solution shows no CPU or GPU load.

Comment: Use *Invalidate(Rectangle)* overload

Comment: This is exactly what I did ;) But anyway, OnPaint is called (even if it doesn't draw on the entire control's surface). OnPaint of a fully featured text editor is quite heavy. So I have to check the approach with a child control.